# ASP.NET Validate Multiple FileUploads

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, file-upload

I want the user to upload 4 photos using FileUpload, and if any of them are empty I would like to display an error message. How can I validate that all of them are filled correctly?

```
<div id="upload-area">
    <div id="photo1">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload1" CssClass="photo-upload" ValidationGroup="PhotoUpload" runat="server" size="38" />
    </div>
    <div id="photo2">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload2" CssClass="photo-upload" ValidationGroup="PhotoUpload" runat="server" size="38" />
    </div>
    <div id="photo3">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload3" CssClass="photo-upload" ValidationGroup="PhotoUpload" runat="server" size="38" />
    </div>
    <div id="photo4">
        <asp:FileUpload ID="PhotoUpload4" CssClass="photo-upload" ValidationGroup="PhotoUpload" runat="server" size="38" />
    </div>
</div>
```

ASP.NET Validator

```
<div id="upload-warning">
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PhotoUploadValidator" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="PhotoUpload1" CssClass="upload-warning">
    <img src="image/mobile/exclamation-mark.png" />
    <span style="vertical-align: middle;">请上传四幅作品，您还需上传一幅作品。</span>
    </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is wrong with `RequiredFieldValidator`?

Comment: i need to display only one message for all 4 fields

Comment: Use `CustomValidator` control (See [post](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/722385/Single-Server-Side-Validator-for-Multiple-Controls))